# What is a neurobiological explanation of borderline personality disorder?

Tags: neuroscience, abnormal-psychology

In other words, how do the brains of those with BPD differ from those who don't have BPD?

[The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borderline_personality_disorder) doesn't even contain any possible explanations whatsoever.

Answer (score 12):

[The Neurobiology and Genetics of Borderline Personality Disorder](http://www.mssm.edu/static_files/MSSM/Files/Research/Programs/Mood%20and%20Personality%20Disorders%20Research%20Program/imaging_genetics.pdf) indicates that a good deal of research has been done but a specific mechanism causing it has not been pinned down. It appears to be largely genetic which would strongly suggest a neurobiological/nature basis as opposed to a "nurture" related cause.
(emphasis mine)

> In summary, the neurobiological research that has been the most useful in 
>   shedding light on the physiology underlying borderline personality disorder has examined 
>   this multifaceted disorder by examining simpler dimensions of behavior separately, 
>   including impulsive aggression and affective instability. **Evidence suggests that impulsive 
>   aggression involves a deficit in serotonergic activity**. However, the specific mechanism 
>   underlying this remains unknown. It is clear that this component of behavior is 
>   substantially genetically encoded, and so new research has focused on elucidating the 
>   specific receptors underlying impulsive aggression through the examination of genes 
>   coding for specific receptors.